# Docker: how to access the hosts network with a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-network

How can I access the hosts network with a docker container? Can I put a container in the hosts network with another IP from the hosts network?

***Current situation:***

- Docker container (default bridge network): 172.17.0.2/16
- Host (server): 10.0.0.2/24

***Question:***

- Can I put the docker container on the 10.0.0.0/24 network as a secondary address?
  (or) Can I access the hosts network on the container and vica versa?

***Reason:***

- I want to access the hosts network from my container (for example: monitoring server).
- I want the container to act as a server accessible from the hosts network on all ports.

***Note:***

- I run several docker containers so a few ports are already forwarded from the host and these should remain so. So an all-port-forward from the hosts IP isn't really a solution here.

***Setup on host:***

- basic docker system
- Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macvlan networks may be the solution you are looking for.
You could assign multiple MAC/IP addresses on virtual NICs over single physical NIC.
There are some prerequisites for using Macvlan.

Comment: okay, I'll take a look at it and get back to you, thx a million!

Comment: I can't believe I went over this so many times and didn't realize that was the solution! Thx :-) it fixed everything.